# How to list local non-admin users in vb6 (or C++) on Windows 10 or 11?

Tags: windows, windows-10, local, windows-11

I'm trying to get a list of users that are not Administrators in Windows 10 (or 11). I know that `net users` from a cmd prompt will show all the users, but how do I do this programmatically, even using C/C++? I have no working example and I can't find anything in stackoverflow or by doing a google search. Hopefully someone can help here?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netuserenum